# Tika LanguageDetection gives error 'No language detectors available'

Tags: apache-tika

Tika 2.2.3, simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LanguageDetector detector =LanguageDetector.getDefaultLanguageDetector();
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        detector.addText("This is english");
        LanguageResult languageResult=detector.detect();
}
```

Last line gives error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language detectors available
    at org.apache.tika.language.detect.LanguageDetector.getDefaultLanguageDetector(LanguageDetector.java:67)
```

**UPDATE** maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-langdetect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-langdetect</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

I cant find anything useful online to fix this problem... am I missing some model files that I must download, where?

Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: can you paste your maven ( or gradle) dependencies related to tika?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and reproduced the same issue. After reading the [docs](https://tika.apache.org/2.3.0/detection.html), which then led to samples in github and I finally found its [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-example/pom.xml) to have another dependency. Then I successfully got the expected output: `en: HIGH (0.999999)`.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-langdetect-optimaize</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
        LanguageDetector detector = LanguageDetector.getDefaultLanguageDetector().loadModels();
        detector.addText("This is english");
        LanguageResult languageResult = detector.detect();
```

*Explanations*

`LanguageDetector` is abstract class, and implementations should be added as dependency.